# Sort an array of dictionaries by keys as Int

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

How can I sort the below array of dictionaries so that the keys of each dictionary are in ascending order, without creating anything new (using .sort not .sorted)? Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!!

**Current array of dictionaries:**

- [[2: 0, 3: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0]]

**What I would like:**

- [[1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0], [1: 0, 2: 0], [1: 0, 2: 0], [1: 0, 2: 0]]

**Code that isn't working:**

```
var arrayOfDicts = [[2: 0, 3: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0]]

arrayOfDicts.sort(by: { $0.keys.first! > $1.keys.first! })

print(arrayOfDicts)
// prints [[2: 0, 3: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0], [2: 0, 1: 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

> so that the keys of each dictionary are in ascending order
>
> ```
>     [[1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0], [1: 0, 2: 0], [1: 0, 2: 0], [1: 0, 2: 0]]
> ```

To say "so that the keys of each dictionary are in ascending order" implies that you want to sort *each actual dictionary* (and that is what appears to be happening in your "what I would like" output). But a dictionary cannot be sorted; the notion is meaningless, because a dictionary has *no order*. The order in which its elements (or keys) are printed is random.

So what you're describing is impossible. You cannot want it. You may *think* you want it, but you don't. It would do you no good whatever; a "sorted" dictionary, if it existed, would change nothing, because it would not affect what the dictionary does, which is not to *list* elements in some order but to *retrieve* values *by key*.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply matt, that makes complete sense! Very sorry about the question, I'm relatively new to coding and was unaware that this wasn't possible/needed...

Comment: Your question is probably an x-y question anyway, meaning that you didn't really ask the question to which you wanted to know the answer. You didn't give any clue as to what you _really_ are trying to do. But, at a guess, it looks to me like you were thinking of an array of _arrays_: `[[0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]`. That does what you seem to want, because we can access each element by _number_, e.g. `myArray[2][1]`. When you want to access something by _number_, that's an _array_; the number is the index of the element within the array.

Comment: Once again thank you very much for your reply. Yes that’s exactly what I would like to do, I’ll give that a go!